# How to show in Auth::user() custom fields of User model?

Tags: laravel, laravel-authentication

On laravel 9.19, laravel/passport": "^11.3 site
I added some more custom fields into users table, and making login method with code like :

```
public function login(Request $request)
{
    if(Auth::attempt(['email' => $request->email, 'password' => $request->password])){
        $user = Auth::user();
        $success['token'] =  $user->createToken('MyApp')->accessToken;
        $success['name'] =  $user->name;
        return $this->sendResponse($success, 'User login successfully.');
    }
    else{
        return $this->sendError('Unauthorised.', ['error'=>'Unauthorised']);
    }
}
```

When I read logged user :

```
$user  = Auth::user();
\Log::info($user);
```

$user has no my custom fields.
Just common app/Models/User.php :

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

// use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Laravel\Passport\HasApiTokens;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasApiTokens, HasFactory, Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array<int, string>
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'email',
        'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for serialization.
     *
     * @var array<int, string>
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password',
        'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast.
     *
     * @var array<string, string>
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];

}
```

How have I to define my custom fields ?

```
"laravel/framework": "^9.19",
"laravel/passport": "^11.3",
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Fields are added via migration. Have you run "php artisan migrate"?

Comment: *I added some more custom fields into users table* What is the field name? Please elaborate more

Comment: You gave to define these fields in the model's protected $fillable array.

Comment: what "fields" is it supposed to have that it does not?